# Query returns incorrect result

Tags: sql, sql-server

MY input table is patient_ID, and Appt_Resource_ID (Doctor) ( the second table is just getting the patient name )

```
Patient_ID     Appt_Resource_ID
88299          47      
88299           1    
88299          40    
88299          40    
88299          40    
88299          40
```

I am running an sql that is meant to write an output row for the patient_id and the Doctor_ID that occurs the most, in this case sb 40. But it's outputting Doctor_ID 1. Other cases I checked are doing correctly.

This is the query:

```
select  distinct A.Patient_id,  P.Patient_name, b.Appt_resource_id
from [PM].[vwGenPatApptInfo] A
inner join 
(
select top 100 percent  patient_id, Appt_resource_id, count(Appt_resource_id) as DR_count,
row_number() over (partition by patient_id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
from [PM].[vwGenPatApptInfo]
where Patient_ID is NOT NULL 
group by patient_id,Appt_resource_id
order by patient_id, seqnum 
) B   on B.Patient_ID = A.Patient_ID  
and  B.seqnum = 1 
inner join [PM].[vwGenPatInfo] P  on A.Patient_id = P.Patient_id
where A.Appt_DateTime >=   DATEADD(yyyy, -2, GETDATE()) and A.Appt_Cancelled_Date is NULL
```

But the results are this:

```
Patient_ID         Appt_Resource_ID
88299                   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM (
    SELECT Patient_ID, Appt_Resource_ID, COUNT(*) AS theCount
    FROM vwGenPatApptInfo
    GROUP BY Patient_ID, Appt_Resource_ID
    WHERE ApptDateTime >= DATEADD(yyyy, -2, GETDATE()) and Appt_Cancelled_Date is NULL
) b
JOIN vwGenPatInfo p ON p.Patient_ID = b.Patient_ID
ORDER BY theCount DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, sorry.

Your subquery finds the doctor that occurs most often for a patient. (If you want the most often occurring patient/doctor pair instead, then remove the partition clause from `ROW_NUMBER`.)

But then you join vwGenPatApptInfo again (as A). Why? And your join is even incomplete, because you only join by Patient_ID and not by Appt_resource_id, too. You are thus combining every most occurring doctor with other doctor records for the patient in a certain date range. These you dismiss again with `DISTINCT`.

I don't see however how your query gets the wrong doctor. If it had been `A.Appt_resource_id` you selected, that would have been a reason, but `b.Appt_resource_id` should be the most often occurring doctor.

I hope my comments above help you, though. Maybe you can simplify your query somehow and maybe get thus even rid of the error.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It might be not the most ideal solution, but try this:

```
;WITH CTE1 as (
    SELECT Patient_ID, Appt_Resource_ID
        , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Patient_ID, Appt_Resource_ID) as CNT
    FROM [PM].[vwGenPatApptInfo]
), CTE2 as (
    SELECT Patient_ID, Appt_Resource_ID, CNT, RANK() OVER   
        (PARTITION BY Patient_ID ORDER BY CNT DESC) AS Rank 
    FROM CTE1
), CTE3 as (
    SELECT Patient_ID, Appt_Resource_ID, CNT, Rank 
    FROM CTE2
    WHERE Rank = 1
    GROUP BY Patient_ID, Appt_Resource_ID, CNT, Rank
)
select  distinct A.Patient_id,  P.Patient_name, b.Appt_resource_id, B.CNT
from [PM].[vwGenPatApptInfo] A
INNER JOIN CTE3 as B on B.Patient_ID = A.Patient_ID
inner join [PM].[vwGenPatInfo] P  on A.Patient_id = P.Patient_id
where A.Appt_DateTime >=   DATEADD(yyyy, -2, GETDATE()) and A.Appt_Cancelled_Date is NULL
```